# Why Can't I install networkD3 and C50 libraries of R on my linux OS

Tags: r, linux-mint, networkd3

I have newly added linux mint 18.3 as an OS alongside windows 10 and I've tried to installa R libraries on R studio I succeeded to install ggplot2, Shiny, formattable and other packages however I could not install C50 and networkD3 for example and I tried installing them from Cran repository directly and from downloaded archives but with no success despite I tried all suggestion that I found on websites and here is what I am getting:

```
Installing package into ‘/home/ali/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  dependencies ‘libcoin’, ‘inum’ are not available
also installing the dependency ‘partykit’

--2018-10-16 18:31:56--  https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/partykit_1.2-2.tar.gz
Resolving cran.rstudio.com (cran.rstudio.com)... 52.85.224.117, 52.85.224.92, 52.85.224.156, ...
Connecting to cran.rstudio.com (cran.rstudio.com)|52.85.224.117|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 1246865 (1.2M) [application/x-gzip]
Saving to: ‘/tmp/RtmpnoeQlL/downloaded_packages/partykit_1.2-2.tar.gz’

     0K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  4%  469K 2s
    50K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  8%  563K 2s
   100K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 12%  400K 2s
   150K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 16%  177K 3s
   200K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 20%  834K 3s
   250K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 24%  385K 2s
   300K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 28%  744K 2s
   350K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 32%  432K 2s
   400K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 36%  844K 2s
   450K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 41%  432K 2s
   500K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 45%  408K 2s
   550K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 49%  714K 1s
   600K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 53%  182K 1s
   650K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 57%  231K 1s
   700K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 61%  996K 1s
   750K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 65%  196K 1s
   800K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 69%  305K 1s
   850K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 73%  388K 1s
   900K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 78%  131K 1s
   950K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 82% 2.70M 1s
  1000K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 86%  226K 0s
  1050K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 90%  510K 0s
  1100K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 94%  352K 0s
  1150K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 98%  263K 0s
  1200K .......... .......                                    100% 2.97M=3.5s

2018-10-16 18:32:00 (349 KB/s) - ‘/tmp/RtmpnoeQlL/downloaded_packages/partykit_1.2-2.tar.gz’ saved [1246865/1246865]

--2018-10-16 18:32:00--  https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/C50_0.1.2.tar.gz
Resolving cran.rstudio.com (cran.rstudio.com)... 52.85.224.101, 52.85.224.117, 52.85.224.92, ...
Connecting to cran.rstudio.com (cran.rstudio.com)|52.85.224.101|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 418240 (408K) [application/x-gzip]
Saving to: ‘/tmp/RtmpnoeQlL/downloaded_packages/C50_0.1.2.tar.gz’

     0K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 12%  568K 1s
    50K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 24%  485K 1s
   100K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 36%  452K 1s
   150K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 48%  152K 1s
   200K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 61%  324K 0s
   250K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 73% 1.63M 0s
   300K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 85%  336K 0s
   350K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 97%  296K 0s
   400K ........                                              100% 60.7M=1.1s

2018-10-16 18:32:02 (361 KB/s) - ‘/tmp/RtmpnoeQlL/downloaded_packages/C50_0.1.2.tar.gz’ saved [418240/418240]

ERROR: dependencies ‘libcoin’, ‘inum’ are not available for package ‘partykit’
* removing ‘/home/ali/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/partykit’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘partykit’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘partykit’ is not available for package ‘C50’
* removing ‘/home/ali/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/C50’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘C50’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpnoeQlL/downloaded_packages’
```

Answer (score 0):

I also got the same error, I searched for this and it was a problem linked with the address where installation files are saved and installed. I succeeded to make it functional for libraries such as 'ggplot2' but I still get this with C50 and network3D:

```
ERROR: dependencies ‘libcoin’, ‘inum’ are not available for package ‘partykit’
* removing ‘/home/ali/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/partykit’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘partykit’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘partykit’ is not available for package ‘C50’
* removing ‘/home/ali/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/C50’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘C50’ had non-zero exit status
```

You may try to download the package from cran and then install it from the downloaded file. It may work for you!